# Transform a string result table from rows to columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pivot

How could I transform a table that looks like this:

| colname | entity |
| --- | --- |
| topic01 | T_pitch |
| topic01 | T_someg |
| topic02 | T_gold |
| topic02 | sp_gpdf |
| topic02 | T_someg |
| topic03 | sp_gpdf2 |

to this

| topic01 | topic02 | topic03 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T_pitch | T_gold | sp_gpdf2 |
| T_someg | sp_gpdf |  |
|  | T_someg |  |

dynamically.

I tried pivoting it, but PIVOT tables are designed to aggregate the results. Using

```
max(entity) for colname in ('+ @columns +')
```

only results in one entity shown under each topic.

Comment: `PIVOT` is an option in your situation, what is your current attempt?

Comment: Your question makes no sense without providing some way of correlating the values across topic columns.  As given, your original table is lacking the ordering you perceive is there.

Comment: Why is `T_gold` related to `T_pitch` and not `T_someg`? There's no relationship(s) defined. Why is `T_someg` *not* related to `T_someg`?

Comment: T_gold is not 'related' to T_pitch. The categories are defined over the first column 'colname'. If I group by colname and string_agg(entity,',') I would get three rows with the corresponding entities delimited by a comma. And what I'm trying to do is to list these entities under the corresponding topic as in the second table above. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you number the rows with `ROW_NUMBER()`, `PIVOT` is an option. The important part here is how do you expect to order the rows.

Sample data:

```
SELECT *
INTO Data
FROM (VALUES  
   ('topic01', 'T_pitch'),
   ('topic01', 'T_someg'),
   ('topic02', 'T_gold'),
   ('topic02', 'sp_gpdf'),
   ('topic02', 'T_someg'),
   ('topic03', 'sp_gpdf2')
) v (colname, entity)
```

Statement for static `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT [topic01], [topic02], [topic03]
FROM (  
   SELECT colname, entity, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY colname ORDER BY entity) AS rn
   FROM Data
) t
PIVOT (
   MAX(entity) FOR colname IN ([topic01], [topic02], [topic03])
) p
```

Results:

| topic01 | topic02 | topic03 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| T_pitch | sp_gpdf | sp_gpdf2 |
| T_someg | T_gold | null |
| null | T_someg | null |

Comment: Thank you! Yes, that exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you so much.